# Performance issue in postgresql

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql-9.3

when I'm trying to use this query in oracle it's taking `0.04054s` and while using the same query in PostgreSQL then it taking `49.8min` how can I change the query to increase performance in PostgreSQL?

```
SELECT
     "ID","IMAGE","TITLE","SERVICE_DESC"
     ,"STATUS", "ACTION","REMOVAL_TEXT","SERVICE_PROVIDER"
     , "SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME" 
FROM ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT "ID","IMAGE"
            ,"TITLE", "SERVICE_DESC"
            , COALESCE("STATUS",'N') as "STATUS"
            ,"ACTION","REMOVAL_TEXT","CREATED_DT"
            ,"SERVICE_PROVIDER", "SERVICE_PROVIDER_NAME"

        FROM MZP_ADP.ALL_SERVICE_DETAILS 
        WHERE "ZIP_CODE"='55005' AND "MAKE_LIVE" = 'Y'
          AND "LOCATION_ID" = '2407605' 
          AND "END_DATE" > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0)::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE 
          AND  "IS_ACTIVE" = 'Y' order by "CREATED_DT" desc
) alias;
```

Comment: Its probably an indexing issue.  You might want to create some indexes fo the columns you are using to filter your query if you haven't already.

Comment: Assuming it's not a serialization problem, your first step is to compare the execution plans for the two executions. Of course, that also assumes the problem is reproducible.

Comment: Why use distinct? Your table have duplicate data.

Comment: yes that's why I'm using distinct

Comment: No one can guess how to improve the query withoun knowing the actual issue. Please, post execution plans in Oracle db and in Postgres as plain texts. How to collect them: 1. Oracle: [DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_XPLAN.html#GUID-2E479BE4-FEEA-400E-A218-DC779A2181CF) with `format => 'TYPICAL +PREDICATE'. 1. Postgres [`EXPLAIN VERBOSE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-explain.html)

Comment: @vaishnavibanait any update about performance.

Comment: I don't know anything about Postgres, but what is the point of the enclosing query? Do you still see the issue if you just execute the inner query on its own (without created_date)?

Answer (score 0):

There can be a lot of problem. (rowcounts, hardwer, no index)

First, what is the rowcounts of table?
Have you inserted a lot of row some time before?
(Then can be REINDEX TABLE TABLE_NAME , And VACUUM ANALYZE TABLE_NAME help.)

CHECK indexes on this columns

- LOCATION_ID
- ZIP_CODE
- CREATED_DT
- END_DATE

Why is the select in subselect?
Please eliminate.

Can you eliminate the distinct with an additional where clause?

Please Share plans and rowcount than can we say more details.

```
EXPLAIN ANALIZE SELECT..
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Create this index

   create index ALL_SERVICE_DETAILS_CMP_INDEX on MZP_ADP.ALL_SERVICE_DETAILS ("ZIP_CODE", "MAKE_LIVE", "LOCATION_ID", "END_DATE", "IS_ACTIVE");
2. Remove parent select
3. Remove distinct (if there is at least one unique column in the select)

Answer (score 0):

**Apply few things for performance boosting**

1. VACUUM FULL for tables (it also rebuild indexes). But any confusion execute rebuild indexes

   VACUUM (FULL, ANALYZE) table_name;

   REINDEX TABLE table_name;
2. Increase work_mem and maintenance_work_mem as per your memory and server
   configuration
3. Use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT (distinct is slower)
4. Remove ORDER BY inside subquery. If needed then use it outside
5. create an composite index with column ZIP_CODE, LOCATION_ID, END_DATE and use
   proper ordering in WHERE clause (As MAKE_LIVE and IS_ACTIVE are flag type so need
   to add first in index)
6. EXPLAIN ANALYZE QUERY for checking execution time and using proper index in query

**Pseudocode:**

```
SELECT columns
FROM (SELECT columns
      FROM table
      WHERE searching columns as per index creation 
      GROUP BY WITHOUT aggregated COLUMNS) t
ORDER BY columns -- if needed
```